# odbc connection oracle log cat error in android

Tags: android, oracle, connection, odbc

i wrote program to connect oracle database 11g for my android application to store values. My table name is names contains three fields. I imported ojdbc.jar file in to my project. After compiling program a log cat error displays like " could not find the class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver() "  like this. Pls give one solution or  is any other jar file i need to import?

```
   package com.odbc;

      import java.sql.Connection;
      import java.sql.DriverManager;
      import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.os.Bundle;

        public class OdbcActivity extends Activity {
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String a="karthick";
    String b="vijay";
    String c="vel";
        try
    {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.2:1521:XE","system","mobile");
            PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into names(name1,name2,name3) values(?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1,a);
            pst.setString(2,b);
            pst.setString(3,c);
            pst.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e);

    }


}
     }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [android odbc connection oracle log cat error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851691/android-odbc-connection-oracle-log-cat-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the ojdbc.jar in libs/ directory under your android project.

See [this page](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17) for a more detailed explanation of why you need to do this with r17.

Comment: can you please tell the path . Bec before i imported add external jars path

Comment: You just need to create a directory parallel to res/ called libs and place the jar there.

Comment: thank you so much it succesfully worked and stored values .. thank you very so so much

Comment: I just found this link that explains the solution more elegantly, leaving it here for future users: http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17 Also, please click accept if the answer worked for you.